# Download dependencies from secured artifactory for sbt project

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I am creating a sbt project where it needs to download the dependencies from secured artifactory. So I have added the artifactory url in resolvers and dependencies in library dependency section of build.sbt like shown below:

```
name := "mts-hook"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

resolvers ++= Seq("MTS Repository" at "https://ccpdev.net/artifactory/libs-release")

credentials += Credentials(new File(".credentials"))

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("ccp.mts" % "mts-server-websocket_2.12" % "0.8.0")
```

And I have added credentials in .credentials file located in class path like below :

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
host=https://ccpdev.net/artifactory/libs-release
user=xxxxx
password=xxxxx
```

Still I am facing the issue like

> UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES

I am not getting where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your artifactory "https://ccpdev.net/artifactory/libs-release" is not having the dependency with name "MTS Repository".

Comment: That helped me, it was supposed to be snapshot . Thanks !